# Javascript prototype function returning NAN

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am following the notes on ES6 from this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) and created a small code snippets to play around.

```
class Bar{
    constructor(x,y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
let bar = new Bar(12,10);
Bar.prototype.foo =function(){
    return this.x + this.y;
}
bar.foo() // 22 correct
```

I am so happy until i do this.

```
let baz = bar.foo
baz(); // NaN
```

Why baz() is printing **NaN** ?

Comment: Because `baz()` doesn't call the function on `bar` (or any object with `x` and `y` properties)

Comment: Please suggest me any modification on question text. It looks like too generic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/218196)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you affect bar.foo to baz, the function loses its context (this). So no more this.x and this.y. Check with breakpoints, you will see that both are undefined.

So adding two undefined together produces a NaN.

Try with this too check in your browser :

```
class Bar{
    constructor(x,y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
let bar = new Bar(12,10);
Bar.prototype.foo =function(){
    debugger;
    return this.x + this.y;
}
```

Try to call it with defining its context. 3 ways to do it :

```
let baz = bar.foo.bind(bar);
baz();

bar.foo.call(bar);

bar.foo.apply(bar);
```

Answer (score 3):

You took a seperate function from an object and you miss [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). To make that work, you need to [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the object to the function.

```js
class Bar{
    constructor(x,y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
let bar = new Bar(12,10);
Bar.prototype.foo =function(){
    return this.x + this.y;
}
console.log(bar.foo()) // 22 correct

let baz = bar.foo.bind(bar); // bind innstance

console.log(baz()); // 22
```